# Why do authors track $\gamma_t$ in Prioritized Experience Replay Paper?

Tags: dqn, deep-rl, experience-replay

In the [original prioritized experience replay paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf), the authors track $\gamma_t$ in every state transition tuple (see line 6 in algorithm below):

[image: algorithm]

Why do the authors track this at every time step?  Also, many blog posts and implementations leave this out (including I believe the [OpenAI implementation](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/deepq/replay_buffer.py) on github).

Can someone explain explicitly how $\gamma_t$ is used in this algorithm?

**Note**: I understand the typical use of $\gamma$ as a discount factor. But typically gamma remains fixed. Which is why I’m curious as to the need to track it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases we may wish to have a discount factor $\gamma_t$ which depends on time $t$ (or depends on state $s_t$ and/or action $a_t$, leading to an indirect dependence on time $t$). Indeed we do not usually do this, but [it does happen sometimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02893).

I guess that, from a theoretical point of view, it was very easy of the authors to make their algorithm more flexible/general and also support this (somewhat rare) case of time-varying discount factor. If it had been very complicated for them to support this option, they may have chosen not to; but if it's trivial to do so, well, why not?

Practical implementations will often indeed ignore that possibility if they're not using it, and can avoid including $\gamma_t$ values in the replay buffer altogether if it is known to be a constant $\gamma_t = \gamma$ for all $t$. As far as I can see, in the experiments discussed in this paper they also only used a fixed, constant $\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do recall in Sutton & Barto the generalization to a variable gamma. But I rarely ever see it used (maybe I’ve never seen a real life implementation that wasn’t for research). I guess I forgot!

Comment: @Hanzy You may also sometimes see similar things in papers for variable $\lambda$ (in Sarsa($\lambda$) and other TD($\lambda$) algorithms) and/or variable learning rates $\alpha$ (although I suppose having time-varying, in particular decreasing, learning rates is quite a bit more common than variable versions of the other things)